# Interchangeable isomers

Tags: isomers

I am a clinical research professional. I have a question regarding clinical chemistry. I would like to know that whether it is possible to get testosterone undecanoate from ursolic acid and vice-versa by the mean of specific chemical reaction or mechanism? Testosterone undecanoate and ursolic acid both have the same chemical formula C30H48O3 and thus molar mass of 456.7g/mol. But the chemical structures, position of functional groups and arrangement of atoms differ, Therefore,can be considered as isomers of each other.

Comment: They're obviously isomers, but there's not much "interchangeable"  here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple reaction that would interchange the two.

Ursolic acid (from Wikipedia)

[image]

Testosterone undecanoate (from Wikipedia)
[image]